# Overriding =~ method on a String subclass generates inconsistency

Tags: ruby, overriding

I overrode the `=~` method for a subclass of `String`:

```
class MyString < String
  def =~(obj)
    "Overridden method."
  end
end
s = MyString.new "abc"
```

The overridden method is correctly called in some cases:

```
r = /abc/
s =~ r             # => "Overridden method."
s.send(:=~, r)     # => "Overridden method."
s.send(:=~, /abc/) # => "Overridden method."
```

while in others it is bypassed, and `String#=~` is called instead:

```
s =~ /abc/         # => 0
s =~ (/abc/)       # => 0
```

I can reproduce these results on Ruby 1.8.7, 2.1.0. Does someone know why this happens? Is it a bug?

Comment: I don't know if it may help but on Ruby 1.9.3 and 2.0, explicitly sending  `=~` works: `s.send "=~", /abc/` #=> "Overriden method.".

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. I think the problem is in [parse.y](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/parse.y#L2229) in MRI. It invokes a different path if the right-hand op is a regexp literal.

Comment: For some reason this also works: `s =~ (/abc/)`, but it would be a hassle to ask users of the class to enclose their `Regexp`s between parentheses.

Comment: In MRI 2.0.0 the parens don't help, @Gabriel. What version are you checking with?

Comment: With the parentheses it's working on 1.8.7.

Comment: I just filed a bug report on [Ruby Trunk](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9581).

Comment: @sawa  the same problem with redefinition of Regexp's class `:=~` method. `/qqq/ =~ 's'` bypassed, while `r=/qqq/;r =~ 's'` works properly

Comment: Just for fun I tried your example on Maglev (a ruby implementation based on the Gemstone/S VM) and it gave `=> "Overridden method."` for all the 5 cases above.

Answer (score 1):

In the source for the [String#=~](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-3D-7E) method, Ruby handles the special case where the argument is of a *built-in* `Regexp` type used by the parser, which is the case when we write `s =~ /abc/`.

The `rb_reg_match` method can be found as being the [Regexp#=~](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-7E) method.

Thus, if you really want this behavior you can monkey patch the `Regexp` class to accept objects of `MyString` for the =~ operator, but that might go wrong very, very easily.

Another approach would be composition. You can either include the [Forwardable](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/forwardable/rdoc/Forwardable.html) module or go with plain old `method_missing`. Here's an example:

```
class MyString
  attr_reader :string

  def initialize(str)
    @string = str
  end

  def method_missing(*args)
    string.public_send(*args)
  end

  def =~(obj)
    "Overriden"
  end
end

s = MyString.new "abc"
s =~ /abc/              # => "Overriden"
s =~ Regexp.new("abc")  # => "Overriden"
```